# Solr import locking up table in postgres

Tags: database, postgresql, solr, locking

I'm busy implementing Solr for a website about holiday homes. The website uses Postgres as the main database. For the search results we want to use Solr as the backend to fetch the available holiday homes.

Importing parts of the database is done by using the DataImportHandler with a JdbcDataSource.

A shortened version of the DataImportHandler:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<dataConfig>
     <dataSource type="JdbcDataSource" driver="org.postgresql.Driver" name="Solr"
                    url="jdbc:postgresql://host:port/database" user="*" password="*" readOnly="true"/>
    <document>
<entity name="availabilities" transformer="RegexTransformer" pk="id"
        query="
            SELECT concat('A',pa.availability_id,'-',pad.start_date,'-',pad.period_type_id) as unique_availability_id,
            pa.property_id,
            NULLIF(CONCAT(ST_X(pl.position),',',ST_Y(pl.position)),',') as locationhash,
            pl.position_accurate,
            true as is_availability,
            region.child_id as city_id,
            region.ancestor_id as province_id,
            (
                SELECT array_to_string(array(SELECT binnen.ancestor_id
                FROM fewo_Location_Ancestry binnen
                WHERE binnen.child_id = region.child_id
                AND   binnen.ancestor_type_id = 12), ',')
            ) AS region_id,
            pl.country_id,
            pl.min_persons,
            pl.max_persons,
            fap.bedrooms,
            pl.specifications,
            pl.property_state_id,
            pa.availability_id,
            pad.period_type_id,
            pad.start_date,
            pad.end_date,
            (
                SELECT COUNT(*) &gt; 0 FROM fewo_last_minute_details flmd
                WHERE flmd.property_id = pa.property_id
                AND flmd.details_id = pad.details_id
                LIMIT 1
            ) AS last_minute,
            CASE (
                SELECT COUNT(*) &gt; 0 FROM fewo_last_minute_details flmd
                WHERE flmd.property_id = pa.property_id
                AND flmd.details_id = pad.details_id
                LIMIT 1
            ) WHEN true THEN pad.discount_price
                    ELSE pad.price
            END as price,
            pl.positioning_fee,
            pl.sort_order   
            FROM fewo_property_availability_details pad
                INNER JOIN fewo_property_availability pa USING (availability_id)
                INNER JOIN fewo_Property_Location pl ON pa.property_id=pl.property_id
                INNER JOIN fewo_all_properties fap ON pl.property_id=fap.property_id
                INNER JOIN fewo_Location_Ancestry region ON (region.child_id =pl.location_id  AND region.ancestor_type_id = 7)
            WHERE pad.start_date &gt; current_date
        ">
    <field name="id" column="unique_availability_id"/>
        <field name="property_id" column="property_id"/>
        <field name="parent_id" column="property_id"/>
        <field name="is_availability" column="is_availability"/>
        <field name="positionCoord" column="locationhash"/>
        <field name="position_accurate" column="position_accurate"/>
        <field name="city_id" column="city_id"/>
        <field name="province_id" column="province_id"/>
        <field name="region_id" column="region_id" splitBy="," sourceColName="region_id"/>
        <field name="country_id" column="country_id"/>
        <field name="min_persons" column="min_persons"/>
        <field name="max_persons" column="max_persons"/>
        <field name="bedrooms" column="bedrooms"/>
        <entity name="fewo_all_property_specifications" transformer="foo.SpecTransformer" pk="property_id"
            cacheKey="property_id"
            cacheLookup="availabilities.property_id"
            query="SELECT property_id, specification_id, COALESCE(value,'true') as val FROM fewo_all_property_specifications"
            processor="CachedSqlEntityProcessor">
        </entity>
        <field name="property_state_id" column="property_state_id"/>
        <field name="availability_id" column="availability_id"/>
        <field name="period_type_id" column="period_type_id"/>
        <field name="start_date" column="start_date"/>
        <field name="end_date" column="end_date"/>
        <field name="last_minute" column="last_minute" />
        <field name="price" column="price"/>
        <field name="positioning_fee" column="positioning_fee"/>
        <field name="sort_order" column="sort_order"/>
    </entity>   
    </document>
</dataConfig>
```

The import runs for about an hour to import 13 million records into Solr. The problem is that during import it is not possible to update the table fewo_property_availability_details because there is an AccessShareLock locking the table. This prevents updating / inserting data into the table and these queries get queued. After a while they stack up too much and the database fails.

My question is: Is there a good way to import the data without obstructing the regular queries too much? Like starting a new transaction after an x number of imported records too give the other queries time to run?

I'm using Solr 4.0 and Postgres 9.1 running on Ubuntu 12.04.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

`AccessShareLock` only conflicts with `AccessExclusiveLock`, as per [the documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/explicit-locking.html)

`ACCESS EXCLUSIVE` is obtained only by `ALTER TABLE`, `DROP TABLE`, `TRUNCATE`, `REINDEX`, `CLUSTER`, `VACUUM FULL` and unqualified `LOCK TABLE` statements.

Take a look at `pg_catalog.pg_locks` to see if you can get more information about what the lock relationships are. You can also find some helpful lock queries on the PostgreSQL wiki: http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Lock_Monitoring

It is entirely possible that rather than locking holding things up, your DB just can't cope with heavy concurrent read/write loads. This is particularly likely if you have small cache, you're running on ordinary (non-SSD) disks without a BBU raid controller, and/or you haven't tuned the PostgreSQL configuration for your environment.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can create a materialized view based on your select from your DIH (in oracle and MySQL it is possible) and than you can set refresh option to FAST (which means that the view will always contains fresh data). What you will achieve:
 - faster import
 - no locks on tables
After that you can do partial imports (not full import) to take just the new or changed data. See this [link](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandlerDeltaQueryViaFullImport)
Hope that will help.